# Qt виджет оффлайн карт

Tags: qt, карты

Добрый вечер. Мне нужен Qt виджет, который позволит мне отображать карту.
Он должен уметь:

1. Отображать карту без сетевого подключения к карте или серверу.
2. На карте отмечать области, точки, информацию о выбранной области учитывая широту и долготу
3. Рассчитывать расстояния между точками.
4. Строить путь по двум заданным точкам.
5. Компиляция в Linux.
6. Выбирать провайдера карт.
7. Добавлять в таблицу название выбранной точки, широту и долготу.

Что можете предложить?

Comment: Если GPL-2 и зависимости от кед не напрягают, то можно взять [marble](https://marble.kde.org/). В программе в том или ином виде большая часть этого всего есть, а библиотеку я не копал.

Comment: Fat-Zer есть уроки, как пользоваться marble?

Comment: lol, вряд ли... хотя гугл знает лучше ;)

Comment: хотя нет, я ошибался, есть официальный неплохой туториал в примерах: https://techbase.kde.org/Marble/MarbleMarbleWidget

Comment: Вспомнил, есть ещё [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) (также GPL-2) — но не знаю, что они в библиотеку вынесли, возможно там только набор для написания модулей... и есть подозрение, что там всё куда серьёзней, чем «броcил виджет на формочку»...